How to find out implicit type conversions in C# code using code analysis way
I'm trying to scan my c# project, to find out which lines have implicit type conversions, then export results to something like a xml file.
ReSharper is a probable resolution.I installed the ReSharper extension in Visual Studio and get this Inlay Hints:

That's exactly what I want. However, I can't find out how to export all hints to a file.eg:
Example.cs:
line 216:implicit conversion of 320 from int to float 
line 222:implict conversion of xxxx from aaa to bbb

Is there any method to find all the locations of implicit type conversions in C# code?
